# Print element does not print the page with the print button, but choosing the data does print it

Tags: javascript

There is a print button in my page, where it opens a popup. If I choose the text, it prints it. But, if I press the print button, it prints 2 blank pages.
I tried printing other pages in the application, and they print normally. It's only the specific pop up that has the printing issue.

The code is typical, there are no errors in it:

```js
ControlHandlers.GridPrint = function(iRecType, sIDs) {
    setTimeout(function() {
          try {
            if (MenuFolders.AppMode == 2) {
              $("#CalendarContainerDiv").printElement();
            }
            if (MenuFolders.AppMode == 3) {
              $("#ActivitiesDiv").printElement();
            }
            if (MenuFolders.AppMode == 4) {
              $("#ContactsDiv").printElement();
            }
            if (MenuFolders.AppMode == 5) {
              if (mo_CustomPage == true) {
                //PrintElem("ReportsContainerDiv");
                $("#ReportsDivEmpty").printElement();
                //   window.print();
                return;
              }

              if (!sIDs) {
                sIDs = '';
              }

              if (!sIDs != '') {
                var keys = BIGrid.getSelectedRowKeys();
                if (keys.length > 0) {
                  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    if (sIDs != '') {
                      sIDs = sIDs + ','
                    };
                    sIDs = sIDs + keys[i].toString();
                  }
                } else {
                  ODCloseBusy();
                  ODAlert(ODGetMsg(2368));
                  return;
                }
              }

              if (iRecType == 1) {
                var query = {
                  iObjectID: BIObjectID,
                  iRecType: 1,
                  sIDs: sIDs
                };

                ODShowBusyWindow();

                FileWindow = true;
                //ShowReport("Download.html?v=2");

                //if (app.isMobileView()) {
                //    FileWindow = window.open("Download.html?v=2", "_blank");
                //} else {
                //    var sParams = "directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=" + Math.round(screen.width / 1.5) + ", height=" + Math.round(screen.height / 1.5) + ", top=" + ((screen.height / 2) - (screen.height / 1.5 / 2)) + ", left=" + ((screen.width / 2) - (screen.width / 1.5 / 2));
                //    FileWindow = window.open("Download.html?v=3", ODGetMsg(27), sParams);
                //}

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "WebMethods.aspx/WaitProcess",
                  //headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip" },
                  data: JSON.stringify(query),
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: true,
                  success: function(result) {
                    var sData;
                    sData = eval('(' + result.d + ')');

                    if (sData.err != "") {
                      ODAlertError(sData.err);
                      ODCloseBusy();
                      return;
                    }

                    DownloadFile(sData.data, "-1", "");

                    ODCloseBusy();
                  },
                  failure: function(msg) {
                    ODCloseBusy();
                    ODAlertError(msg);
                  },
                  error: function(a, b, c) {
                    ODCloseBusy();
                    ODAlertError(c + ' - ' + a.responseText);
                  }
                });

                return;
              }; //EKTYPWSH LISTAS

              if (BIGridPrintField != '') {
                if (BIForcePrintFile != '') {
                  DownloadFile(BIForcePrintFile, "-1", "");
                  BIForcePrintFile = "";
                  return;
                }

                if (BIData && (BIData[BIGridPrintField] == '' || !BIData[BIGridPrintField])) {
                  ODAlertError(ODGetMsg(12061));
                } else {
                  var FilesToPrint = '';

                  var selectedRowsData = BIGrid.getSelectedRowsData();
                  for (i = 0; i < selectedRowsData.length; i++) {
                    if (FilesToPrint != '') {
                      FilesToPrint = FilesToPrint + '|'
                    };
                    if (selectedRowsData[i][BIGridPrintField] != '') {
                      FilesToPrint = FilesToPrint + selectedRowsData[i][BIGridPrintField];
                    }
                  }

                  //BIData[BIGridPrintField]
                  DownloadFile(FilesToPrint, "-1", "");
                }
              } else {
                $("#ReportsDiv").printElement();
              }
            }
          } catch (e) {
            ControlHandlers.ODAlertError(e);
          }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please do not just post a code dump and expect us to eyeball debug it. You likely have some CSS that influences your printing

Comment: The rest of the code is not relevant to the printing method. But I can send the whole page if it helps you.

Comment: Any error message and what does the ajax do, interrogate the printer?

Comment: No, there no error messages. It prints normally if I choose the text.